# Sharepoint 2016 MySite layout difference

Tags: master-page, 2016, mysite

I am encountering two different layouts of the mysite host (profile.aspx) in different environments, and cannot figure out why.

The difference is that the profile picture switches from the left hand side to a banner at the top with a much smaller image.

Was this changed in some recent CU?

Cannot find any feature differences between the sites.

Platform: SharePoint 2016
Master page for both environments: mysite15.master

[image: Design 1]

[image: Design 2]

Comment: What is patch level on both farm? Anyone has November 2016 cu or later?

Comment: Left hand side image: 16 0 4534 1000 ,
Banner: 16 0 4456 1000

Comment: So November and May

Comment: What I am thinking, one farm had modern one drive enabled and other dont.

Answer (score 0):

What I am thinking, one had modern one drive for business feature enabled and other won't.

You can try below code to disable and enable modern experience.

To enable:

```
$Farm = Get-SPFarm
$Farm.OneDriveUserExperienceVersion = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.OneDriveUserExperienceVersion]::Version2 

$Farm.Update()
```

To disable:

```
$Farm = Get-SPFarm
$Farm.OneDriveUserExperienceVersion = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.OneDriveUserExperienceVersion]::Version1 

$Farm.Update()
```

Comment: They were different, but changing it did not update the profile layout. Maybe there is a timer job that has to sync something?

Comment: (did iisreset on farm)

Comment: Tested recreating mysite host with the version switched (from 2-->1) and the profile looks the same.